# How to make sticky headers in UICollectionView on iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm using [this solution](http://blog.radi.ws/post/32905838158/sticky-headers-for-uicollectionview-using) to make sticky headers in collection view and it works well on iOS6. But in iOS7 if the "Extend edges under top bars" option is checked then the header sticks to the origin of the view which is then behind the navigation bar.

So for now I disabled that option but I'd really like to tweak that solution to make it work when the edges are extended (in order to have the nice blurry effect when the content scrolls behind the navigation bar).

Can someone help me with that? Or does someone have any other suggestions to accomplish the same goal?

Comment: Sounds like you need to make use of `topLayoutGuide`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my full solution. Just add the following to your FlowLayout class:

```
#pragma mark STICKY HEADERS CODE BELOW
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSMutableArray *answer = [[super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:rect] mutableCopy];

    NSMutableIndexSet *missingSections = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];
    for (NSUInteger idx=0; idx<[answer count]; idx++) {
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = answer[idx];

        if (layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategoryCell || layoutAttributes.representedElementCategory == UICollectionElementCategorySupplementaryView) {
            [missingSections addIndex:(NSUInteger) layoutAttributes.indexPath.section];  // remember that we need to layout header for this section
        }
        if ([layoutAttributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
            [answer removeObjectAtIndex:idx];  // remove layout of header done by our super, we will do it right later
            idx--;
        }
    }

//    layout all headers needed for the rect using self code
    [missingSections enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:idx];
        UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader atIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (layoutAttributes) {
            [answer addObject:layoutAttributes];
        }
    }];

    return answer;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([kind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
        UICollectionView * const cv = self.collectionView;

        CGFloat topOffset = 0;
        if ([self.collectionView.dataSource isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
            UIViewController *collectionViewParentViewController = (UIViewController *)self.collectionView.dataSource;
            topOffset = collectionViewParentViewController.topLayoutGuide.length;
        }

        CGPoint const contentOffset = CGPointMake(cv.contentOffset.x, cv.contentOffset.y + topOffset);
        CGPoint nextHeaderOrigin = CGPointMake(INFINITY, INFINITY);

        if (indexPath.section+1 < [cv numberOfSections]) {
            UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *nextHeaderAttributes = [super layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection:indexPath.section+1]];
            nextHeaderOrigin = nextHeaderAttributes.frame.origin;
        }

        CGRect frame = attributes.frame;
        if (self.scrollDirection == UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical) {
            frame.origin.y = MIN(MAX(contentOffset.y, frame.origin.y), nextHeaderOrigin.y - CGRectGetHeight(frame));
        }
        else {
            frame.origin.x = MIN(MAX(contentOffset.x, frame.origin.x), nextHeaderOrigin.x - CGRectGetWidth(frame));
        }
        attributes.zIndex = 1024;
        attributes.frame = frame;
    }

    return attributes;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return attributes;
}

- (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self layoutAttributesForSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return attributes;
}

- (BOOL)shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:(CGRect)newBound {
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your solution? Dropping it into a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass does not seem to work.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show the full implementation, as requested by @AndrewTheis

Comment: This can be simplified and generalized by just using the collection view's `contentInset` instead of trying to get into the view controller hierarchy to get the `topLayoutGuide`.

Comment: As you can see from the date of my original response, this is now quite old. Feel free to post a simplified solution @HiltonCampbell.